# Angular 4 - I keep getting Cannot find module 'portfinder' even after installing portfinder manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I keep getting this error in my Terminal using **ng serve** in terminal, I already tried `='npm install portfinder`, also `npm uninstall -g angular-cli, npm cache clean, npm install npm -g, npm install -g angular-cli`, but none working and I keep getting it, I'm using npm 3.10.10, Angular4 and the error as below:

```
Cannot find module 'portfinder'
Error: Cannot find module 'portfinder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.includedCommands (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/index.js:21:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:392:61
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Project.addonCommands (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:391:15)
    at Project.eachAddonCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:426:30)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
    at CLI.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:34:26)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:215:12)
    at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:230:13)
    at publish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/-internal.js:198:7)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/lib/rsvp/asap.js:82:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solve the problem, the issue was double node on my computer, (that's why even after installing portfinder, I still get Cannot find module 'portfinder') basically if you install node via wizard and homebrew, they get installed in different places by default, so what I did, I delete any node folder in my mac via this way which I find:

```
# first:
lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.pkg.bom | while read f; do  sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*

# To recap, the best way (I've found) to completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:

# go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo rm -rf node*

# go to /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory
cd /usr/local/include
sudo rm -rf node*

# if you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in your terminal
brew uninstall node

# check your Home directory for any "local" or "lib" or "include" folders, and delete any "node" or "node_modules" from there
# go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
ls -las

# you may need to do the additional instructions as well:
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
```

This way all folders containing node get cleared, so I install node through homebrew and install yarn, angular cli, react-native cli etc...

I was thinking to share this, hope helping other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need node v4.x to get it work also another alternative is going to angular-cli folder and installing portfinder there with `npm install portfinder`. If a local npm install portfinder fails to fix the issue, a global install of portfinder should work.

Comment: Go to angular-cli folder and install portfinder there with npm install portfinder.